# Import Export is not working in magento 1.7

Tags: php, layout, importexport

Trying to export Magento single products but only a blank page is appearing. could not export any products either from **System ->Import/Export->Export** or from **System->Import/Export/Dataflow-profile**.

when trying to import just five products from **System ->Import/Export->Import** and by choosing a file to import when I click on "**check data**" button, file is just loading but it doesn't respond any thing, neither it generate any error/warning nor Import button is appearing.

I checked log file to see the error I got

```
  2014-05-08T09:33:05+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 58233  in /var/www/vhosts/Outletzon.secureserver.net/httpdocs/testdocs/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php on line 873

 2014-05-08T09:47:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():     </catalog_product_view>  in /var/www/vhosts/Outletzon.secureserver.net/httpdocs/testdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
 2014-05-08T09:47:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                            ^  in /var/www/vhosts/Outletzon.secureserver.net/httpdocs/testdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
  2014-05-08T09:47:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 104: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/vhosts/Outletzon.secureserver.net/httpdocs/testdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
  2014-05-08T09:47:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():     <catalog_category_default>  in /var/www/vhosts/Outletzon.secureserver.net/httpdocs/testdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
  2014-05-08T09:47:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:      ^  in /var/www/vhosts/Outletzon.secureserver.net/httpdocs/testdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
```

I don't know what's going wrong suddenly..it was working before. I have imported around 50 k products by same way. but now its not working at all.
 Please someone help me to get me out of this problem.

Comment: One of your 3rd party modules or core hacks has invalid XML code.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have a syntax error in one of your layout xml files (app/design/*/*/*/layout/*.xml). You should do a full text search for `</catalog_product_view>` in those directories. You should find the error near to this text in one of the found files.

Comment: I could not found any such error in layout..is there any other cause I have to look around ?